# Not able to retry Camel Route continuously in case of specific exception

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am very new to Apache camel, I have a situation where I need to perform below action

Whenever I receive specific type of Exception, I need to retry the complete route again,
But I am facing problem of circular-error handling exception and infinite recursion when implementing using onException.

Below is my dummy code

```
 from("direct:updateTheTask")
.to("direct:getWoTaskDetail")
.to("direct:getSoTaskDetail")
.to("direct:updateTaskDetail")
.to("direct:getSoTaskDetail")   
.to("direct:getWoTaskDetail")
.to("direct:endRoute");


 from("direct:updateTaskDetail").routeId("updateTaskDetail")
.bean(BEAN, Constants.SET_PARAMS)
.to("direct:restUpdate")
.to(getGetResponseBeanUrl(BEAN));
```

I have a call to "direct:updateTheTask" route and "direct:updateTaskDetail" is giving exception in my case when exception is received I want to retry again from "direct:updateTheTask" maintaining/persisit the data in exchange.

When no such exception is thrown by "direct:updateTaskDetail"  during this recursion the route should be completed normally.

I have used below 2 approach but seems it is not working for me.

```
onException(TaskException.class)
.handled(true)
.maximumRedeliveries(-1)
.redeliveryDelay(20);
```

The other approach is

```
onException(TaskException.class)
.handled(true)
.delay(20)
.to("direct:updateTheTroubleTicket");
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the error handler in the task route so when calling this route, Camel will retry the entire route, instead of the route error handler will retry at the point off the error.

```
from("direct:updateTheTask")
  .errorHandler(noErrorHandler());
  .to("direct:getWoTaskDetail")
```